# Value of variable is changing without actually changing it in C

Tags: c, binary-search

In the binary search code below value of key is changing automatically after calling the function binarySearch(). Despite the fact key is passed as reference in function binarySearch(). Please let me know what is happening in background which is changing the value of Key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int binarySearch(int arr[], int key, int low, int high, int *middle){
    if(arr[*middle] == key)
        return *middle+1;
    else if(arr[*middle] > key && arr[*middle] > 0){
        high = *middle--;
        *middle = (low + high)/2;
        return binarySearch(arr, key, low, high, middle);
    }
    else if(arr[*middle] < key && key < arr[high]){
        low = *middle++;
        *middle = (low + high)/2;
        return binarySearch(arr, key, low, high, middle);
    }
 return -1;
}
main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int key;
    int low = 0;
    int high = size - 1;
    int middle = (low + middle)/2;
    printf("Enter the key to be Searched: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("%d", key);
    int result = binarySearch(arr, key, low, high, &middle);
    printf("%d", key);  
}
```

Comment: `*middle--` doesn't do what you want it to; try `(*middle)--`. (Similarly for `*middle++`.)

Comment: Just for clarification of the previous comment: Due to the [rules of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `*middle--` is equivalent to `*(middle--)`.

Comment: `int middle = (low + middle)/2;` uses the uninitialized value of `middle`, which is Undefined Behavior. Probably it ends up too large and you go past the end of the array into the memory used by other variables. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @aschepler: That is certainly a bug (and UB) but in practical terms it's unlikely to be causing the issue described in the question, because even if `middle` points outside the array it's only ever used for reading, so is unlikely to cause overwriting of memory.